# ui.grid data displayed is the same on each row

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

I am using a cell template for each row in my data grid.  If I qualify the json object with an index then the value appears correctly but of course it is the same for each row.  If I remove the index, then all rows are displayed with the same value but the value is an array.

---the js file 
(function() {
    angular.module('xxxSurvey').controller('EditxxxSurveyController', EditxxxSurveyController);
    EditxxxSurveyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'UserFacilityListService', 'xxxSurveyService'];
    function EditxxxSurveyController($scope, UserFacilityListService, xxxSurveyService) {
        $scope.dataLoaded = false;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.pageSize = 10;

```
    // test ui-grid setup

    $scope.dataLoaded = true;

    $scope.editWorksheetOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [
            {
                name: 'all', field: 'MasterPatientId', width: 40,
                enableSorting: false, enableColumnMenu: false, pinnedLeft: true,
                //cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" id="i{{COL_FIELD}}">'
                cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.worksheetInfo.MasterProviderId}}</div>'
            },


            {name: 'residentName', field: 'residentName', minWidth: 90, pinnedLeft: true,
                cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.editWorksheetOptions.data[0].ResidentNameLast}}</div>'
            },
            {name: 'residentRoom', field: 'residentRoom', width: 90, pinnedLeft: true},
            {name: 'status', field: 'status', width: 90},
        ],
        data: []
    };

    $scope.$on('FacilitySelected', function() {
        if (UserFacilityListService.getSelectedFacility()) {
            $scope.selectedFacility = UserFacilityListService.getSelectedFacility();
        }
        var promise = xxxSurveyService.getCurrentWorksheet($scope.selectedFacility.MasterProviderId);
        promise.then(
            function(payload) {
                if (payload !== null) {
                    $scope.worksheetInfo = payload.worksheetInfo;
                    $scope.editWorksheetOptions.data = payload.residentData;


                }
            }
        );
    });

}
```

})();

--the json data

[{"AssessmentId":1,"WorksheetId":4,"MasterPatientId":1,"ResidentNameFirst":"xx","ResidentNameMiddle":"^","ResidentNameLast":"zzz","ResidentNameSuffix":"^"},
{"AssessmentId":2,"WorksheetId":2,"MasterPatientId":2,"ResidentNameFirst":null,"ResidentNameMiddle":null,"ResidentNameLast":null,"ResidentNameSuffix":null}]

--the html div id="editWorksheetGrid" ui-grid="editWorksheetOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-pinning>

Comment: Here is the html - <div id="editWorksheetGrid" ui-grid="editWorksheetOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-pinning></div>

Comment: show more of the js code you are using to bind the array to the grid...

Comment: Do I need to have ng-repeat on div?

Comment: var promise = myserviceService.getCurrentWorksheet($scope.selectedFacility.MasterProviderId);
            promise.then(
                function(payload) {
                    if (payload !== null) {
                        $scope.worksheetInfo = payload.worksheetInfo;
                        $scope.editWorksheetOptions.data = payload.residentData;

Comment: This is the grid declaration:        $scope.editWorksheetOptions = {
            enableSorting: true,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                               {name: 'residentName', field: 'residentName', minWidth: 90, pinnedLeft: true,
                    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.editWorksheetOptions.data[0].ResidentNameLast}}</div>'
                },],
            data: []

Comment: Put your code sample on the original question. Would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue. For me it was rowIdentity problem.
Define following in your controller.

```
$scope.gridOptions.rowIdentity = function (row) {
    return row.ID;  //make sure ID is unique.
};
```

This fixed my problem.
Thanks